# json object print in div

Tags: jquery, json

I have an object like:

```
{"result":
[
  {"id_":"18","name":"papas","species":"Other","sex":"F"},

{"id_":"26","name":"as","species":"bird","sex":"M"}

]}
```

How can I access each item, and print it inside a div?

I am trying:

```
$.each( myObj , function(index,item){
   $("#wrapper_busqueda").append('<div><b>' + myObj.id_ + '</b>  '+ myObj.mame  + ' </div><hr />');
}
```

but get undefined...

Comment: You have a typo... myObj.mame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop..

```
var OBJ = {"result":[{"id_":"18","name":"papas","species":"Other","sex":"F"},
{"id_":"26","name":"as","species":"bird","sex":"M"}]};

var total = OBJ['result'], myString = '';
for(i=0;i<total.length;i++)
{
    myString += '<div><b>' + total[i].id_ + '</b>  '+ total[i].mame  + ' </div><hr />';
}
$("#wrapper_busqueda").append(myString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use as follows

```
$.each( myObj , function(index,item){
   $("#wrapper_busqueda").append('<div><b>' + item.id_ + '</b>  '+ item.mame  + ' </div><hr />');
}
```

It seems that you have multi dymension

```
for(var list in response)
{
   for(var item in list)
   {
     alert(item);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

apart from the typo, you should access your `myObj` like this:

```
myObj['result']
```

and use `item` of the `.each` to access current item values and not directly myObj
i.e. do `item.name` and not `myOBj.name`

hence

```
$.each( myObj['result'] , function(index,item){
   $("#wrapper_busqueda")
   .append('<div><b>' + item.id_ + '</b>  '+ item.name  + ' </div><hr />');
 });
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/62x7D/)